# Can I request all push notifications sent to device to show in screen?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

I need create a screen in Flutter using firebase-messaging with all notifications received, with date and status (read or not). But I can just save when I receive with app is open.

So, I need a way to request for firebase all push sent to device and show in a ListView

Thanks

Comment: Do you want like an app running in active mode and receive notification?

Comment: yes, I want to save notifications in array to show in app

Comment: Use `OverlaySupport` and try to make view with timer

Comment: I saved all sent notifications in database table and created an endpoint to return this in app. Thanks for help